# Changing color of a button too slow

Tags: java, colors

I'm currently making a game of Reversi for my programming class and I wanted to try and implement a computer into the game.  I got this working successfully, but the computer makes their move instantly so you can't see how your move worked.

I tried solving this by using the following method:

```
public void wait (int n) {
    long t0, t1;
    t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    do {
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } while ((t1-t0) < n);
}
```

I then called this method after the player made their move, right before it called my `computerAI()` method.

However, it didn't work quite right and it seems like it hit the wait before it changes the colors of the board, because the player clicks, the background changes to the default light gray, and then after it waits a second, it performs the color changes of your move and the computers.

Anyone have any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: But where is your redrawing code? Can you please paste it, too?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

This causes the current thread to sleep for 5 seconds.

Comment: This causes the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need not only change button's color property, but also call its `.repaint()` or even `.update()` method often enough, e.g. every 100 ms. That is, you need to make the button actually redraw itself on the screen when you need it, not when the system determines it has time to render the accumulated changes.

Comment: I already call repaint whenever I change the color of a button, but I just tried also adding a loop that calls repaint on every button again directly before it calls wait(1000) which is directly before it calls computerAI().

For this class, I have created a custom button class called CircleButton.  Here is the code for that:
http://pastebin.com/CtgXWEe2

Here is the code that makes the move and calls changeColor.  It's a lot to read through but in brief, it finds what directions, it wants to change, and changes the colors.  It then gets through it all, waits, and calls the AI.

Comment: Forgot to paste the second link and ran out of time to edit:
http://pastebin.com/NvJSPp4L